# Full text is not printing to a text file in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a program which parses text for specific words, and if these words are found, I'd print the line a and 4 lines after it, then search for the next sequence and do the same. When using print in the interactive terminal, it works, it prints all matching key words, however, when i try to write it to a text file, it writes one sequence and closes it. Any idea why or how I can print the full text showing in terminal in the text file instead of four lines only?

```
for j in os.listdir(path):
 if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,j)) and 'nameoffile' in j:

 print  '\n'
 print j
 print  '\n'
 os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Windowslogs"))
 file = open(j, 'r')
 codes = 'error '
 for line_app in appenforce_file:
  if codes in line_app:
  #print (line_app +  ''.join(islice(appenforce_file, 4)))
   with open("streamedlog.txt", 'w') as f:
   f.write(line_app +  ''.join(islice(appenforce_file, 4)))
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. Please use more than one space to indent (4 preferred), otherwise your code is very hard to read. Parts of your indentation are just plain wrong for Python.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to the programming/scripting world, will be changing my indentation now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with open("streamedlog.txt", 'w') as f:`

That `w` flag tells open to "truncate the contents of the file, and write the following content there". You should either open the file before the start of the loop (and avoid opening it multiple times), or you should use the `a` flag instead, to append the file.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the open before the loop and it's now printing everything! :)